# Equally distributed bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

**What I want to do**

My dataset consists of several cases (`id`) with different outcomes (`outcome`) for a given number of repeated meaures (`cycle`). Each cycle should be counted as 1 (`val`) or be visualized of equal length.
The plot I want to end up with is a stacked bar chart, where each cycle of each case has the same length. The sequence of cycles must be continous. The sequence of the outcomes is dependent on the according cycles.

**My Problem**

The sample code below produces a bar chart that sums up the cycles (although being a factor). However, using the `val` column instead of `cycle` messes with the sequence of the outcomes, which must not change.

```
# setup
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)    
set.seed(0)

# test data
data.frame(
  cycle=factor(rep(1:8,2),levels=1:8),
  val=1,
  id=factor(rep(1:2,each=8)),
  outcome=factor(paste("Outcome",sample(1:8,16,T)),levels=paste("Outcome",1:8))) %>%

  # plot
  ggplot(.,aes(id,cycle,fill=outcome))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_stack(reverse=T),width=0.99)+
  coord_flip()
```

**My Question**

Is it possible to make cycles count as 1 for each id, keeping the outcome sequence?

Thank you in advance!

**The Plots**

This is what I get when using the above code:

[image]

This is what I get, when using `val` instead of `cycle`:

[image]

The goal is to keep the outcome sequence, while counting each cycle as 1 or making them appear of the same length for each id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I get it you could achieve your desired result using `geom_tile`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(0)

dat <- data.frame(
  cycle = factor(rep(1:8, 2), levels = 1:8),
  val = 1,
  id = factor(rep(1:2, each = 8)),
  outcome = factor(paste("Outcome", sample(1:8, 16, T)), levels = paste("Outcome", 1:8))
)

ggplot(dat, aes(cycle, id, fill = outcome)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]